# Convert leaflet geojsonFeature object's coordinates array from decimal to integer values

Tags: arrays, leaflet, coordinates, turfjs

I need to convert/display leaflet coordinates from decimal to integer values in multiple objects in order to use it in turfjs mehod:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/boolean-point-in-polygon

```
coord = geojsonFeature.geometry.coordinates:

{type: "D", designator: "EPD53A", availabilities: Array(1), info: Array(2), geometry: {…}}
{type: "TRA", designator: "EPTR105", availabilities: Array(1), info: Array(2), geometry: {…}}
{type: "D", designator: "UMD192", availabilities: Array(1), info: Array(2), geometry: {…}}
(...)

geometry:
  type: "Polygon"
    coordinates: Array(1)
      0: Array(8):
        0: (2) [16.845, 54.587777778]
        1: (2) [16.647777778, 54.515]
        2: (2) [16.545277778, 54.543611111]
        (...)
```

Is there any simple way to do it? (angular/typescript)

I'm trying to check if clicked point is laying on two or more layer polygons. Do I really need to convert this values to integer?

```
    var pt2 = turf.point([22.65380859375, 49.710272582105695]);
    var multiPoly = turf.multiPolygon([[[
        [22.828611111111112, 49.68472222222222],
        [23.065833333333334, 49.9],
        [23.20861111111111, 49.843333333333334],
        [22.98611111111111, 49.650555555555556],
        [22.828611111111112, 49.68472222222222],
        [22.828611111111112, 49.68472222222222],
        [22.828611111111112, 49.68472222222222]
    ]]]);
    console.log("test-turf",turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt2, multiPoly));
```

It returns false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All TurfJS methods accept (well-formed) GeoJSON as input. There is no need to use integer values for the coordinates.

> It returns false

Your call to `boolanPointInPolygon` returns false because that point is outside that polygon:

[image: Map with point and polygon plotted]

Comment: Thank you for paying attention. I forgot to check this obvious detail, Everything is works how it should.